# \renewcommand for \forall to add a parameter

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors

Hi I'm trying to redefine the `\forall` command so that it accepts an argument instead of using the regular juxtaposition.

What it looks like at the moment is

```
\renewcommand{\forall}[1]{\forall{(#1)}\;}
```

which doesn't work on

```
\forall{(u,v) \in V \times V}
```

producing the error message:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

\forall #1-&gt;\forall (
                     #1)\;
```

However the following works fine albeit would require to substitute every occurrence of `\forall` in the document:

```
\newcommand{\all}[1]{\forall{(#1)}\;}
```

Is there an intrinsic recursiveness in that redefinition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition is a recursion. Do

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\ForAll\forall
\renewcommand\forall[1]{\ForAll{(#1)}\;}
\begin{document}

$\forall{(u,v) \in V \times V}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Plus, plesae consider writing the `for all` part as words instead, it makes the text much more readable than having symbols all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't change the semantics of a standard command. It's probably better to define `\Forall`:

```
\newcommand{\Forall}[1]{\forall{(#1)}\;}
```

rather than redefining `\forall`.

Just for fun, a “`\let` free” solution of your problem, should you decide to disobey:

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\forall#1{\mathchar\number\forall{(#1)}\noexpand\;}

\begin{document}

$\forall{(u,v) \in V \times V}$

\end{document}
```

A bit more difficult with `\renewcommand`, but doable:

```
\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\forall\expandafter[\expandafter1\expandafter]%
\expandafter{\expandafter\mathchar\number\forall{(#1)}\;}
```

or

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \unexpanded{\renewcommand\forall[1]}{\mathchar\number\forall{(##1)}\noexpand\;}%
}\x
```

Comment: show off.......;-)